# imagesx() and imagesy() not working

Tags: php, gd, thumbnails

I am trying to make a thumbnail. And the php function works. I've made thumbnails with it. However, certain files do not work. I have narrowed down the problem, but am now stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

The images can be found at http://www.pspsigma.com/image_test.php .The one on the left will not work. The one on the right will. Both are .jpg. Both are originally uploaded via a form, but have been altered for stack overflow so that the function works without a form.

The html is a simple script with file input set action to this .php file

the php:

```
<?php
    $the_name= $_FILES['userfile']['name']; 
    $tmpname = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];  



    $size="1000";
      $save_dir="images/thumbs/";
      $save_name=$the_name;
      $maxisheight= "100";

function img_resize( $tmpname, $size, $save_dir, $save_name, $maxisheight)
{
$save_dir     .= ( substr($save_dir,-1) != "/") ? "/" : "";
$gis        = getimagesize($tmpname);
$type        = $gis[2];
switch($type)
    {
    case "1": $imorig = imagecreatefromgif($tmpname); break;
    case "2": $imorig = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpname);break;
    case "3": $imorig = imagecreatefrompng($tmpname); break;
    default:  $imorig = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpname);
    }

    //check if imorig is set
    if (!isset($imorig)) {
    echo " imorig is not set, ";    
    }

    //I tried setting $x and $y from the width and height of the original file. Still didn't work.
    //although the variables were set.
    //this makes me think the problem is with the imagecreatefromjpeg function.
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($tmpname);
    echo "getimagesize width= " . $width . ", ";
    echo "getimagesize height= " . $height . ", ";

    //possible solution, didn't work
    //$x = $width;
    //$y = $height;

    //This is the problem
    $x = imagesx($imorig);
    $y = imagesy($imorig);

    //check that x and y are set
    if (!isset($x) && !isset($y)) {
        echo" x and y are not set,";
    }
    elseif (!isset($x)) {
        echo" x is not set";
    }
    elseif (!isset($y)) {
        echo" y is not set";
    }
    else {
    echo "|x= " . $x . " |";
    echo "|y= " . $y . " |";            
    }


    $woh = (!$maxisheight)? $gis[0] : $gis[1] ;   


    if($woh <= $size)
    {
    $aw = $x;
    $ah = $y;
    }
        else
    {
        if(!$maxisheight){
            $aw = $size;
            $ah = $size * $y / $x;
        } else {
            $aw = $size * $x / $y;
            $ah = $size;
        }
    }   
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor($aw,$ah);
    if (!$im) {
        echo " failure: no im variable. ";
    }
    else {

if (imagecopyresampled($im,$imorig , 0,0,0,0,$aw,$ah,$x,$y)) {
    if (!imagejpeg($im, $save_dir.$save_name)) {
        echo "failure";}
        else {
        echo "success";}
}
else {
    echo" didn't copy resampled";
}
    }
}


img_resize( $tmpname, $size, $save_dir, $save_name, $maxisheight);
?>
```

If I choose the rush vader.jpg file and put it through this function. it echo's that x and y are set, displays their values ,and success.

If I choose the calm.jpg it will echo "failure: no im variable." and the $x and $y variables will not have values. If I assign the x and y variables the values from getimagesize($tmp_name) it echoes "didn't copy resampled".

Is this a problem with the actual image? or is there some way I can change the code so that every image works?

THANK YOU!!!

**UPDATE**

I echo'd every variable to see if something was off. The problem appears to be in the type. The type is output as 6 which from the php manual comments i found out is bmp.

I don't understand how that could be if the extension is .jpg... If this is the case. Is a way to change the type to make it either .jpg, .png, or .gif?

Comment: Could you choose `calm.jpg` and before `imagecreatetruecolor`, do `var_dump($aw); var_dump($ah);`. Thus we may understand what is happening.

Comment: The function doesn't even get that far. It fail around where $x and $y are set. Although, would the var_dump provide some benefit? What does it do? and I don't understand what you mean could I choose calm.jpg?

Comment: If you read PHP page of `imagecreatetruecolor`, it returns `false` on failure. This function fails either because of parameters, or GD library. Since you are telling that it works for some image, this means that there is no problem about GD library. Therefore, the only problem I see is that this functions parameters have not suitable values. By using `var_dump`, we can see what those parameters have as value and understand what is the reason of real problem. You said "_If I choose the calm.jpg it will echo "failure: no im variable."_". Thus, what I am saying is choose it again with those codes

Comment: I just did that and the values returned NULL and NULL. The full echo from the script is "getimagesize width= 400, getimagesize height= 563, x and y are not set, NULL NULL failure: no im variable."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type from the image calm.jpg is 6 which is a bmp. Therefore the imagecreatefrom... will not work and $imorig is NULL. By adding a function from the php manual called imagecreatefrombmp with label 6. The function works perfecty.

Add to the file:

```
function imagecreatefrombmp($p_sFile)  { 
    //    Load the image into a string 
    $file    =    fopen($p_sFile,"rb"); 
    $read    =    fread($file,10); 
    while(!feof($file)&&($read<>"")) 
        $read    .=    fread($file,1024); 

    $temp    =    unpack("H*",$read); 
    $hex    =    $temp[1]; 
    $header    =    substr($hex,0,108); 

    //    Process the header 
    //    Structure: http://www.fastgraph.com/help/bmp_header_format.html 
    if (substr($header,0,4)=="424d") 
    { 
        //    Cut it in parts of 2 bytes 
        $header_parts    =    str_split($header,2); 

        //    Get the width        4 bytes 
        $width            =    hexdec($header_parts[19].$header_parts[18]); 

        //    Get the height        4 bytes 
        $height            =    hexdec($header_parts[23].$header_parts[22]); 

         //    Get the horz. resolution in pixel per meter, 4 bytes
        $dpix = hexdec($header_parts[39]. $header_parts[38]) * 0.0254;

        //    Get the vert. resolution in pixel per meter, 4 bytes
        $dpiy = hexdec($header_parts[43]. $header_parts[42]) * 0.0254;

        //    Unset the header params 
        unset($header_parts); 
    } 

    //    Define starting X and Y 
    $x                =    0; 
    $y                =    1; 

    //    Create newimage 
    $image            =    imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height); 

    //    Grab the body from the image 
    $body            =    substr($hex,108); 

    //    Calculate if padding at the end-line is needed 
    //    Divided by two to keep overview. 
    //    1 byte = 2 HEX-chars 
    $body_size        =    (strlen($body)/2); 
    $header_size    =    ($width*$height); 

    //    Use end-line padding? Only when needed 
    $usePadding        =    ($body_size>($header_size*3)+4); 

    //    Using a for-loop with index-calculation instaid of str_split to avoid large memory consumption
    //    Calculate the next DWORD-position in the body 
    for ($i=0;$i<$body_size;$i+=3) 
    { 
        //    Calculate line-ending and padding 
        if ($x>=$width) 
        { 
            //    If padding needed, ignore image-padding 
            //    Shift i to the ending of the current 32-bit-block 
            if ($usePadding) 
                $i    +=    $width%4; 

            //    Reset horizontal position 
            $x    =    0; 

            //    Raise the height-position (bottom-up) 
            $y++; 

            //    Reached the image-height? Break the for-loop 
            if ($y>$height) 
                break; 
        } 

        //    Calculation of the RGB-pixel (defined as BGR in image-data) 
        //    Define $i_pos as absolute position in the body 
        $i_pos    =    $i*2; 
        $r        =    hexdec($body[$i_pos+4].$body[$i_pos+5]); 
        $g        =    hexdec($body[$i_pos+2].$body[$i_pos+3]); 
        $b        =    hexdec($body[$i_pos].$body[$i_pos+1]); 

        //    Calculate and draw the pixel 
        $color    =    imagecolorallocate($image,$r,$g,$b); 
        imagesetpixel($image,$x,$height-$y,$color); 

        //    Raise the horizontal position 
        $x++; 
    } 

    //    Unset the body / free the memory 
    unset($body); 

    //    Return image-object 
    return ($image); 
    return ($dpix); 
    return ($dpiy); 
}
```

add:

```
case "6": $imorig = imagecreatefrombmp($tmpname); break;
case "15": $imorig = imagecreatefromwbmp($tmpname); break;
```

after

```
case "3": $imorig = imagecreatefrompng($tmpname); break;
```

Tested. and everything works. Thanks all!